# Replace all white spaces with commas in a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I need to replace all white spaces inside my text with commas. I'm currently using this line but it doesn't work: I get as output a text file which is exactly the same of the original one:

```
sed 's/[:blank:]+/,/g' orig.txt > modified.txt
```

thanks

Comment: sed  's/[[:blank:]]\+/,/g'

Comment: @mug896 worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04
I needed the double square brackets and the \ before the +

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' orig.txt > modified.txt
```

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -pne 's/\s+/,/g' < orig.txt > modified.txt
```

**Edit:** To exclude newlines in Perl you could use a double negative `'s/[^\S\n]+/,/g'` or match against just the white space characters of your choice `'s/[ \t\r\f]+/,/g'`.

Comment: Thanks, however there is still an issue: I don't want to replace "next lines \n" with a comma, and the command with perl is currently doing it. She sed command you wrote, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry you need to escape the `+` operator in sed, I just updated my answer. Newlines are whitepsace in perl, so you will have to do your whitepsace class manually if you don't wnat to include it. I added two solutions for that as wel.

Answer (score 21):

Using `tr`:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' <file
```

This will replace any horizontal whitespace with a comma.  Any repeated whitespace will only be replaced with a single comma.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your command,

```bsh
sed 's/[:blank:]+/,/g' orig.txt > modified.txt
```

is twofold:

1. The `[:blank:]` is a bracketed expression matching one of the characters `:`, `a`, `b`, `k`, `l`, or `n`.  If you want to match one of the characters in the POSIX character class `[:blank:]`, use `[[:blank:]]`.
2. The `+` is an extended regular expression modifier.  The `sed` utility uses *basic* regular expressions, and the `+` would match a literal `+` character.  To get the same effect in a basic regular expression, use `\{1,\}`, or, in this particular expression, use `[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*` instead.

In short, your corrected `sed` expression would be

```bsh
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/,/g' orig.txt >modified.txt
```

or

```bsh
sed 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/,/g' orig.txt >modified.txt
```

As others have pointed out, and assuming single byte ASCII characters in the text, it may be more efficient to use `tr` in this case, as it's a simple transliteration of one set of characters to another.  Either one of the following two `tr` commands would solve the issue:

```bsh
tr -s '[:blank:]' '[,*]' <orig.txt >modified.txt
```

where `[,*]` means "as many commas as is needed for this set to match the number of characters in the first set", or

```bsh
tr -s '\t ' ',,' <orig.txt >modified.txt
```

The `-s` option to `tr` causes multiple consecutive commas to be "squeezed" into single commas.

Comment: Note that some `tr` implementations including GNU `tr` only work correctly with single-byte characters, so they would fail to handle blank characters such as U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK, U+2000 EN QUAD, U+2001 EM QUAD, U+2002 EN SPACE, U+2003 EM SPACE, U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE, U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE, U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE, U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE, U+2009 THIN SPACE, U+200A HAIR SPACE, U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE, U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE in those locales where those characters are encoded on more than one byte (like those using UTF-8 as their charmap)...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hair space? I lack a philosophical space...  But much thanks, as usual. I keep on learning.

Comment: See also [Command to retrieve the list of characters in a given character class in the current locale](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128192) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Hair_spaces_around_dashes

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- `~$ vim filename`
- `:set nu` (just for setting lines)
- `:%s/ /,/g` (this will replace space to comma)
- `:wq!` (save and exit)

Comment: Note that the user wants to also replace tabs ("all white-spaces").  It is clear from their attempted command that they don't want multiple consecutive commas in the resulting text, even if there are multiple consecutive spaces or tabs in the original.  Also consider formatting your answer using the tools provided.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{print $1","}' Servers | tr -d '[\n]' | xargs echo
```

Here the file name is Servers..
It contains the below content..

```
Server1
Server2
Server3
```

If we use the above command we can get the below output..

```
Server1,Server2,Server3,


[mohramak@oc3246038448 Desktop]$ cat Servers
Server1
Server2
Server3
[mohramak@oc3246038448 Desktop]$ awk '{print $1","}' Servers | tr -d '[\n]' | xargs echo 
Server1,Server2,Server3,
[mohramak@oc3246038448 Desktop]$
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally I found Steven D's answer to work the best for subbing out spaces for a character. In my case it was with the 'date' command echoed out as a variable as a prefix to log files I was creating. Automated it very easily with the help of his command.

```
prefix=$(date | awk -F' ' '{print $1,$2,$3,$6}' | tr -s '[:blank:]' '-')
```

then

```
ScriptToGatherImportantLogs.sh > $prefix-logfile.txt
```

I didn't know tr was a command. If you do tr --help you can see all of the characters listed in the man page for what it subs out.
Thanks OP and Steven! This was extremely helpful!